# Silverlight 4 Getting full exceptions

Tags: c#, vb.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a silverlight application elevated trust deployed at my company and some errors I get the "debugging resource strings are unavailable" I was wondering if there was any way currently for silverlight 4 to get the full error message without installing the developer version of silverlight on every single machine.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this article helps u... [Check this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlightws/archive/2008/04/06/getting-full-exceptions-in-silverlight-2-beta-1.aspx)

By default, the full exception strings are not enabled in silverlight. You need to enable it in the **slr.dll.managed_manifest** file.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the code giving the exception in try/catch brackets and then use MessageBox.Show to display the error message;

```cs
try
{
    // Code that crashes
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e);
}
```

Exception also contains some other useful variables.
Hope this helps.