# Silverlight Exceptions on Server

Tags: exception, silverlight-4.0, resources

I am running a silverlight application on a web server. Now the users keep getting exceptions and all I ever see is this message (in the error log) and the stacktrace isn't very helpful either.

"[Arg_NullReferenceException] Argumente: Debuggingressourcen-Zeichenfolgen sind nicht verfügbar. Oft enthalten der Schlüssel und die Argumente genügend Informationen zur Diagnose des Problems. Weitere Informationen erhalten Sie unter http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.60831.0&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=Arg_NullReferenceException"

The users don't debug or anything, so any idea why it's complaining about the debugging resources missing? Is there any way to get a better error message? Does what is described at [Silverlight 4 Getting full exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879697/silverlight-4-getting-full-exceptions) also work on the server for normal users?

Most of the time it seems to show up when the NotifyChanges fails. Any ideas are welcome =)
Thanks

Comment: thanks, seems like I found it at exactly the same time =) I put it down as an answer, or would it be better to delete the post?